# Parse DateTime? format from ajax to asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I would like to parse `DateTime?`  from ajax to asp.net mvc controller.

I have following code, where @Model.DateA and @Model.DateB is in `DateTime?` class. The error i got is uncaught syntax error: unexpected number

```
[HttpPost]
public class CheckDate(DateTime? datea, DateTime? dateb)
{
}

$.ajax({
  ...
  data: {'datea': @Model.DateA, 'dateb': @Model.DateB }
  ....
});
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the date values with quotes `{'datea': '@Model.DateA', 'dateb': '@Model.DateB' }`?

Comment: I assume you mean `public ActionResult CheckDate(..`?

Comment: What is the point of this? Your just (trying) to post back exactly the same values you sent to the view in the first place so whatever `CheckDate()` does could have been done in the GET method before you render the view.

Comment: because user can change the date input for that after first render

Comment: @desmondlee, `@Model.DateA` and `@Model.DateB` are the original values when you first render the view (razor code code is parsed on the server - I suggest you inspect the html you generate to understand). You need to pass the value of the textbox.

Comment: yeah i get wat u mean, i have solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use Moment.js. Moment is prepared to deal with almost every date-format passed to it: ASP.NET JSON Dates, String Dates, UNIX, ISO, etc. In this example i'm using Knockout just to show you the output...

```
//Here you can do this
//var datea = '@Model.DateA.toString()';
//var dateb = '@Model.DateB.toString()';

var datea = "01/23/2015 15:00:00.000";
var dateb = "01/24/2015 15:00:00.000";


//Knockout just to show you date
function MainViewModel(){

    var self = this;

    //Here i pass to moment.js the date, and format it
    //year-month-day; this way is standard for every country
    self.datea = ko.observable(moment(datea).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    self.dateb = ko.observable(moment(dateb).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));



    self.sendData = function(){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/CheckDate", //Your controller method
            type: "POST",
            data: { datea : self.datea(), dateb: self.dateb() } //Send date values
        });

        request.done(function(data){
            //Do something with the response...
        });

    };
}
var vm = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

For your CheckDate() you are using a class, maybe you want to use JsonResult and send the return with JSON. Something like this:

```
public JsonResult CheckDate(DateTime? datea, DateTime? dateb){
    //Check dates   
    return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

That might solve your problem. Greetings.

Ah!... [JSBIN working](http://jsbin.com/bofave/1/edit)

Answer (score -1):

convert it to a string first :

```
@Model.DateA.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: And what if the model is `null`!

Comment: Then first check if it is null like this `Model.DateA.HasValue ? Model.DateA.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : null;`

Comment: Make no difference anyway. If the value of `DateA` is `DateTimeToday` then both `@Model.DateA` and `@Model.DateA.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")` render identical output (23-0-2015) assuming the server culture is `MM-dd-yyyy`